# How do I add two (or more) random single digit numbers with a mathematical operator and show that in a label + the answer in the console

Tags: swift, xcode, function, integer

In my function "updateQues" I have created three random integer values between 0 and 10 and added those three values. I accessed my questionLabel and put those three values added together as text in String format. So the output I get when i run the value is the total of those three numbers added together will show (an e.g answer being "25". My question is how I would show the text to be "10 + 9 + 6" aswell as saving the answer (25 in this case). would this be possible?

```
     import UIKit 

     class GameScreenViewController: UIViewController {
        
                @IBOutlet weak var answerTxtLabel: UITextField!
                @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
                
                func updateQues() {
                    let number = Int.random(in: 0...10) + Int.random(in: 0...10) + Int.random(in: 0...10)
            
                    questionLabel.text = String(number) //put number value in the question Label
                    print(number) //print output in the console
        
                }
                   override func viewDidLoad() {
                   updateQues() // run updateQues function at start
                   super.viewDidLoad()
           
                   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
               }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed issue here:

Actually
`Int.random(in: 0...10) + Int.random(in: 0...10) + Int.random(in: 0...10)` is adding all number **because they are treated as integer**.

To fix you have to put values in `" "` like in below code:

```
        var correctAnswer: Int = 0
    
      func updateQues() {
            let firstRandwom = Int.random(in: 0...10)
            let secondRandwom = Int.random(in: 0...10)
            let thirdRandwom = Int.random(in: 0...10)
            correctAnswer = firstRandwom+secondRandwom+thirdRandwom
            
            let number = "\(firstRandwom) + \(secondRandwom) + \(thirdRandwom)"
            print(number) //Print: 1+3+4
            print(correctAnswer) //Print: 8
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful.  However, I should have added to my question that I would like to save the answer and print it to the console as well as showcase the question on the label just like you managed.

Comment: So i gave correct answer. Could you please upvote and mark my answer correct.

Comment: you helped alot however in the console it prints the question instead of the answer, i need to find a way for the console to print the answer only